# Unable to connect from desktop application to a website

Tags: java, proxy

I have created a Java desktop application. One of its buttons checks updates by connecting to my website and checking some files.

One of the application users cannot check the updates, as he gets "Connection error". He said that he connects to my website through a proxy server. I am not professional in Networking, **so could this be the reason of the connection failure ?**

*Here is the code i use to connect from the program to the website* :

```
URL url = new URL( "www.mywebsite.com" ) );
URLConnection conn = (URLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout( 20000 );
conn.setDoOutput( true );
conn.setDoInput( true );
conn.connect();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proxy is probably interfering. If possible, get the proxy details from the user, and pass them via the command line:

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.domain.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.noProxyHosts="localhost|host.mydomain.com" MainClass
```

Alternatively, you can prompt the user in the program, and then set the required values through `System.setProperty`:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxy.mydomain.com");
System.setPropery("http.proxyPort", "8080");
```

Edit: Here's a complete guide: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html.

Comment: http.proxySet is an urban myth. It has no effect.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited it for future reference. I have no idea why I included that, it wasn't in the documentation.

Comment: It is in some books, including the early Nutshell editions. It apparently leaked from history into legend from the very shortlived HotJavaBean of 1997. It has never been part of the JDK.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/proxy_setup.xml) looks like it might be causing issues.  Make sure your user has configured Java to use the system's proxy settings instead of using a direct connection.